# Help with "hello world" pbsdsh

Tags: parallel-processing, multicore, pbs, torque

I want to test whether `pbsdsh` works or not in my system. I use the following programme

I am using a linux server with two 64-bit quad-core Intel Xeon (24 compute nodes

```
try.sh

#!/bin/bash

# Set up the path
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH

# Make all hosts print out "Hello World"
pbsdsh echo Hello World
```

then I issue the command

```
qsub -l nodes=2 try.sh
```

I got the following error message in `try.sh.e2013`

```
/var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/2013.hpc.SC: line 8: pbsdsh: command not found
```

This error message is misleading as `pbsdsh` does exist in the system.

Could anyone help me out with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "This error message is misleading as
>   pbsdsh does exist in the system."

Does it exist in `PATH`?   And, in particular, does it exist in `PATH` on the compute nodes on which it's being run?  Keep in mind that the `$PATH` variable in the environment of this script may be different than in an interactive shell on the head node; you can find this out by echoing `$PATH` in your script.   Try submitting an interactive job

```
$ qsub -I -l nodes=2
```

and then, when you have an interactive shell on one of the nodes, find pbsdsh and make sure it's where you think it is.

Comment: @Jonathan. Thanks for your input. I just did what you have suggested with > qsub -I -l nodes=2 
Then >"echo $PATH" , it gives the following /usr/local/bin:/share1/mpich2-1.2.1/bin:/share1/pgi/linux86-64/2010/mpi/mpich/bin:/share1/pgi/linux86-64/10.1/bin:/share1/bin:/opt/kusu/bin:/opt/kusu/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/share1/matlab-R2009a/bin:/home2/Tony/bin. What is the next step?

Comment: @Tony : good; next step is to see if pbsdsh does exist in one of those directories.   You said that pbsdsh does exist in the system; that sounds like you know where it is.   Is it in that place on the compute nodes?  If yes, is that directory in the PATH above?

Comment: (PS - on my system, it's in /opt/torque/bin/)

Comment: pshdsh is located in /usr/local/bin. It is not in the PATH when echoed. Is this explained why the system prompts the error message? Should pdsdsh  be in /opt/torque/bin/?

Comment: Shouldn't matter where it is.   So when you `qsub -I` onto the compute nodes, do you see pbsdsh in /usr/local/bin?  (It's often the case that compute nodes have different setups than the head or login nodes).

Comment: After accessing to the compute node. I issue the command pbsdsh , it prompts  "-bash: pbsdsh: command not found". What is the solution to this ? It seems it is not in the PATH.

Comment: Right, but is it in `/usr/local/bin`?  If you type `/usr/local/bin/pbsdsh`, does it run?  If you `ls /usr/local/bin/pbsdsh` do you see it?  One possibility is that it simply isn't installed on the compute nodes, in which case you need to ask your sysadmin to install it.   Otherwise, if it is there and you're still not getting it by default, just specify the path: eg, run `/usr/local/bin/pbsdsh` rather than `pbsdsh` and it should execute.